# My website layout completely shift top left of the browser screenm when I zoom out from my browser?

Tags: html, css, browser, layout

My website layout completely shift top left of the browser screen, when I zoom out from my browser?

While when I check some website, like yahoo.com and zoom out from browser. It stays in center.

Comment: I think you are using a template made from Microsoft Word or Publisher, or some other basic .html template. Normally, you have a "cascading style sheet" or .css file, which directs the browser to draw various objects against the rule-sheet. (It may center the body, set percentages like proportions depending on screen size, etc.) Can you please post a link to your site?

Comment: Are you referring to 'zooming' in iOS and on mobile devices or are you talking about using ctrl + / ctrl - to increase text size?

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is kind of old, but maybe it can help some other people.

### The layout sticks to the left

I guess your layout sticks to the left because it is not centered. If you want to center an element of the layout, you have to use the following css code:

```
.my_element{
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

It means "0 pixel on the top and the bottom, and a same amount of pixels on the left and on the right" (horizontaly centered).

But be careful, you cannot use this "trick" if the element has no width:

```
.my_element{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}
```

Here is a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jmaylin/UL3uf/) on jsfiddle. In this example, every element is centered horizontaly.

But we can do better. In this [**second demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jmaylin/Vhf9x/), we add a **wrapper** that contains every element and we just have to center it.

### The layout sticks to the top

If you don't want your layout to stick to the top, you just have to set a **margin-top** on the first div, which is the **wrapper** in our example:

```
.wrapper{
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Note that english is not my native language, if you see some mistakes, please let me know.