# Website shift to left when pinch zoom (iOS)

Tags: html, css

My website has a weird behaviour on pinch zoom. Problems happens only in iOS Safari browser. It seems to shift the whole site to the left and won't allow me to scroll from left to right.

I've done a lot of research about this. I found this question that seems to have the same problem I do.

[My website layout completely shift top left of the browser screenm when I zoom out from my browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106752/my-website-layout-completely-shift-top-left-of-the-browser-screenm-when-i-zoom-o)

I tried changing the meta viewport to any variations of

```
<meta id="Viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height,initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1">
```

I've tried changing my fixed header to a relative position. I've had no luck researching this issue either, since everything coming up is either about applications or about disabling the pinch zoom entirely which isn't an option for me.

Here's the website : http://www.chocolato.ca/

Many thanks!

Comment: It's definitely caused by JS. When you disable it, it doesn't happen. Try to deactivate your JS-modules one by one and find the root cause like this. I'd start with any JS that sets height/width/position/display.

Comment: Indeed, I finally found the culprit! A script was disabling the X scroll by sticking it to the left. Thanks for the tip!